# How to properly display AJAX post data return

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://offcloud.com/api/cloud/status',
        data: {'requestId' : 'theid'},
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true, // enable this
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
        success: function(data) { 
            var stringData =JSON.stringify(data);
            el.innerHTML = "<pre lang='xml'>" + stringData + "</pre>";
            console.log(data); 
        },
        error: function() { console.log('Failed!'); }
    });
```

This is what is displayed:

```
{"data":[{"accountId":"5xxx","remoteOptionId":"yyyyyy","type":"gdrive","username":"email@gmail.com"}]}
```

However, I want it properly displayed in XML format. Or any actually readable format, a table, (preferably a table).  Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Use jQuery datatables.

Answer (score 0):

Set `Content-Type: application/xml` in request

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the JSON format, you don't need `JSON.stringify(data)`, all it does is convert the returned object into the string you see in order to be quickly displayable.

In your `success` function, you can access the individual values like this:

```
var accountId = data[0].accountId;
```

Or, if that doesn't work (because I'm not entirely sure why you have `data` in your return value), try the following:

```
var accountId = data.data[0].accountId;
```

Then you could manually insert those values into your output like this

```
"<accountId>" + accountId + "</accountId>"; // XML format
"<td>" + accountId + "</td>"; // HTML table cell
```

...or find a framework or library that does it for you.